# cannot bring up image by javafx application

Tags: javafx

I am new to Stack overflow and asking generally questions in an open forum. I am aiming to display a gif file using javafx. I have created a directory inside the directory that host my class file and I cannot bring the file to show-up.

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUmCN.png)
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI0DJ.png)

Anyone has faced this issue?

Comment: The location is throwing the error. Try: Image image = new Image("/image/us.gif");

Comment: Post an mcve.  The first listing in the Oracle [JavaFX ImageOps tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/image_ops.htm#JFXGR238) demonstrates image display.  The example code in the [Image javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) provides commented examples on how JavaFX locates image files.

Comment: Image has an [error property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#isError--) and an [exception property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#getException--) that you can check to get some indication of what may have gone wrong.

Comment: thanks @Eric I needed to add the folder containing the image on the build path of eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Eric and jewelsea. I obtained the picture show after I added the image folder in my build path and it worked.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vodng.png)

[add image to build path library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBm7s.png)

In eclipse: Go to folder project -> build path/configure path-> add image folder  containing image to build path library